# Can we have an option to close a question for being easily answerable?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

We often have on this site questions that are very easily answered in the comment (even [so simple](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72471/how-does-this-quote-relate-to-karl-poppers-theory) that it could've been sorted with a quick google search).

I wouldn't go into examples as there are too many to count (obviously even some of [my questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72298/is-it-possible-to-fully-automate-scientific-observation)).

What I'd like to ask is for an option in the closing vote for community specific->easy question or something like that (with a better phrasing of course).

I'd like to add that we have **too many** questions on the site that don't have answers (not sure if one can see it statistically) but rather simply answered in the comments (which might be a bad habit, but there are many questions that simply don't require more than that). Staying with the given closing options is simply not enough because there is currently no reason that fits this kind of cases and not closing them just leaves us with a bunch of unanswered questions (and I'm not sure if there's anything like a answered/unanswered questions ratio calculation for SE, but if there is it's certainly a bad influence on it).

Answer (score 3):

Very basic questions (or homework questions) are often closed with this close reason:

> This question is missing context. Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Or in other words, if a question seems too basic to you, then it's not doing an adequate job of explaining why the asker still has trouble understanding.

Comment: This is the closest option we have currently, but it's inadequate. The sort of questions I'm referring to aren't ones that with additional context would be "better" (i.e. harder? more sophisticated?). These are simply easy questions.